# Add class in html tag with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I got this html code:

```
<form id = "xxx">
   <ul>
     <li class = "req" > </li>
     <li class = "req" > </li>
     <li class = "req" > </li>
     <li > </li>    ==================> HOW CAN I ADD A CLASS="req" to this li with jquery
     <li class = "req" > </li>
     ....
    <li class = "req" > </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

So I rewrite the question: There is one li tag that has not ( class= "req"), how can i add that with jquery?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#xxx li").addClass("req");
```

is sufficient.

If you want to explicitly add it to only the `li` without `req`, you can do:

```
$("#xxx li:not(.req)").addClass("req");
```

If you want to only add the class to the fourth element, you would do:

```
$("#xxx li:eq(3)").addClass("req");
```

The `3` is because it uses a [zero-based index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393462/defend-zero-based-arrays) for the elements.

Comment: oh yes wonderful ! it works, but sorry, don't move am comin with another question

Comment: There  are an other li tag without class req, but i don't want to add to theme the class, just to this one ! can i play with position ? or something like that ??

Comment: if it's always the fourth li inside that ul, you can do: `$("#xxx li").eq(3).addClass("req");`. Start counting by 0, so the fourth is number 3.

Answer (score 1):

With not you can check if an item has a certain attr.

```
$("ul#yourid").not(".req").addClas("req");
```

Comment: Can i add a class just to this li? The solution you gave work but i forgot i could have an other li without class, i mean it's not unique and it has not an a id

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery('li').addClass('req');`